# Reading HTML contents of a URL in OCaml

Tags: html, url, ocaml

I would like to write an OCaml function which takes a URL and returns a string made up of the contents of the HTML file at that location. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Best,
Surikator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've done both of those things using ocurl and nethtml

[ocurl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ocurl/) to read the contents of the URL (tons of properties here; this is the minimum),

```
let string_of_uri uri = 
    try let connection = Curl.init () and write_buff = Buffer.create 1763 in
        Curl.set_writefunction connection
                (fun x -> Buffer.add_string write_buff x; String.length x);
        Curl.set_url connection uri;
        Curl.perform connection;
        Curl.global_cleanup ();
        Buffer.contents write_buff;
    with _ -> raise (IO_ERROR uri)
```

and from [nethtml](http://ocamlnet.sourceforge.net/); (you might need to set up a DTD for `Nethtml.parse`)

```
let parse_html_string uri = 
    let ch = new Netchannels.input_string (string_of_uri uri) in
    let docs = Nethtml.parse ?return_pis:(Some false) ch in
    ch # close_in ();
    docs
```

Cheers!

Comment: @nlucaroni Thanks a lot for the answer. It's exactly what I wanted. Some quick questions: (1) can I use your string_of_uri function for URLs containing other files (e.g. JPEG file) to analyze parts of the contents of that file (don't worry about the meaning of it, but worry about encodings)? (2) I wasn't able to install ocurl (GODI told me: > File "lifetime.ml", line 16, characters 25-36:
> Error: Unbound value Date.to_mjd), any ideas?

Comment: 1)Oh yeah. totally filetype agnostic. 2) I think I installed it from source; godi has consistently failed me.

Comment: Actaully, i just looked at the ocurl source; I don't see a 'lifetime.ml' file (or Date module) at all!! Must be from some weird dependency? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again. Are there any important dependencies you can think of when you installed it from source?

Comment: The file is from the library .../godi/lib/ocaml/pkg-lib/calendar lifetime.ml

Comment: Interesting; I don't see `Calendar` as a dependency in `ocurl` or `ocamlnet`! Other dependencies? `ocurl` is just a wrapper for `libcurl`, so that. As for `ocamlnet`, I think you'll need `PCRE`.

Comment: I just installed `ocamlnet` from source (my work computer didn't have it). I needed to change one line in `src/shell/shell_fs.ml` (under ocaml 3.11.1). I added the type annotation for the variable `ci` (to type `command_interpreter`) for the `shell_fs` class.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake. The error was because GODI was installing some other packages at the same time and referred to missing dependencies for that package. It did install curl perfectly well and your code is compiling fine. I'll have a play with it. Thanks!

Comment: OK, everything was right with the ocurl bit, but I don't have nethtml... should I install ocamlnet 3? Thanks!

Comment: `nethtml` is a part of `netstring`, if that helps.

Comment: Great stuff! Yes, I've managed to install ocamlnet in Godi and it all went very smoothly. Like you mentioned, I had some problems in the past trying to put ocamlnet working in Godi but this time there were no issues. For building with ocamlbuild, I only had to include the libraries: curl, netsys, pcre, netstring. It all works fine and your code compiles fine. Thanks a lot, once again!

Comment: @nlucaroni One last thing, regarding redirects. Do you know what I can do in your "string_of_uri" function to follow any redirects that the website may be doing on the URL I'm attempting to consult? I tried to find documentation on ocurl but I think it's not available.

Comment: I recalled it was available somewhere; I couldn't find it either though. You'll have to browse the source file or how it would be done in libcurl, and find the analogous functions. I'm not sure, maybe `set_followlocation`?

Comment: @nlucaroni I've just posted a question in the forum regarding this, before I read your comment here. I'll try `set_followlocation`. Thanks!

Comment: @nlucaroni, no need to call global_cleanup (actually it may harm when used with other code using ocurl), use `Curl.cleanup connection`. Also one should probably check the HTTP return code.

Comment: @ygrek Thanks for the insight. (1) So what's the difference there between `global_cleanup` and `cleanup`? (2) How would you check HTTP return code? (3) Finally, do you know of any website where to get more info on ocurl functions?

Comment: ocurl is a thin wrapper over libcurl, so `man curl_easy_cleanup`, `man curl_global_cleanup` and `less $(ocamlfind query curl)/curl.mli` are your friends.