# Following HTTP redirects in OCaml web crawler

Tags: html, http, web-crawler, ocaml

### What I'm doing

I am writing a web crawler in OCaml. Using the function `string_of_uri` (below) defined by [nlucaroni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157/nlucaroni) in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621454/reading-html-contents-of-a-url-in-ocaml/4622158#4622158) to a question I posted, I can fetch the HTML text of a URL from the web.

```
let string_of_uri uri = 
try let connection = Curl.init () and write_buff = Buffer.create 1763 in
    Curl.set_writefunction connection
            (fun x -> Buffer.add_string write_buff x; String.length x);
    Curl.set_url connection uri;
    Curl.perform connection;
    Curl.global_cleanup ();
    Buffer.contents write_buff;
with _ -> raise (IO_ERROR uri)
```

I've already written some code to extract a list of all the hyperlinks in the fetched HTML (i.e. all the [LINK] parts in anything like `<A HREF="[LINK]">text</A>`). This all works fine.

### The Problem

The problem is that some pages redirect you and I don't know how to follow the redirection. For example, my program will output 0  tags in the page http://en.wikipedia.org because Wikipedia will actually redirect you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page. If I give this last page to my program, it all works fine. But if I give the initial one, it just returns 0 `<A>` tags.

Unfortunately there's no documentation at all for [ocurl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ocurl/), except for the names of the functions in the interface. Does any one have an idea on **how I can improve the function `string_of_uri` above so that it follows any possible redirections** and outputs the HTML of the last page it falls in?

I noticed that applying the function `Curl.get_redirectcount` to a `connection` on http://en.wikipedia.org returns 0, which is not what I was expecting, since the page is redirected to some other page...

Thanks for any help!

All the best,
Surikator.

Comment: Surikator, I recommend you to add your own answer (just copy the first paragraph as the answer) and mark it as the correct one, because if you don't ever do it this question will appear forever in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocaml ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621454/reading-html-contents-of-a-url-in-ocaml/4622158#4622158). The solution is to add `Curl.set_followlocation connection true` just above `Curl.perform connection`.